# Sencha touch 2 - show response (JSON string) on proxy loading

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a way to output the json-string read by my store in sencha touch 2?

My store is not reading the records so I'm trying to see where went wrong.
My store is defined as follows:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Online", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
           config: {
           model: 'NotesApp.model.Note',
           storeId: 'Online',
           proxy: {
               type: 'jsonp',
               url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/qa.php',
               reader: {
                   type: 'json',
                   rootProperty: 'results'
               }
           },
           autoLoad: false,
           listeners: {
               load: function() {   
                    console.log("updating");
                   // Clear proxy from offline store
                   Ext.getStore('Notes').getProxy().clear();
                   console.log("updating1");
                   // Loop through records and fill the offline store


                    this.each(function(record) {
                             console.log("updating2");
                             Ext.getStore('Notes').add(record.data);

                   });

                   // Sync the offline store
                   Ext.getStore('Notes').sync();
                   console.log("updating3");
                   // Remove data from online store
                   this.removeAll();
                    console.log("updated");
               }

           },
           fields: [
                    {
                    name: 'id'
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'dateCreated'
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'question'
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'answer'
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'type'                    
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'author'
                    }
                    ]
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to explicitly observe your response results if you are using a configured `proxy` (It's obviously easy if you manually send a `Ext.Ajax.request` or `Ext.JsonP.request`).

However, you can still watch your results from your browser's developer tools.

**For Google Chrome:**

When you start your application and assume that your request is completed. Switch to **Network** tab. The hightlighted link on the left-side panel is the API url from which I fetched data. And on the right panel, choose **Response**. The response result will appear there. If you have nothing, it's likely that you've triggered a bad request.

[image: dev tool]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you may get all the data returned by the server through the proxy, like this:

```
store.getProxy().getReader().rawData
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the data (javascript objects) returned by the server through the proxy as [lasaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617728/lasaro) suggests:

```
store.getProxy().getReader().rawData
```

To get the JSON string of the raw data (the reader should be a JSON reader) you can do:

```
Ext.encode(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData)

//or if you don't like 'shorthands':
Ext.JSON.encode(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData)
```

You can also get it by handling the store load event:

```
// add this in the store config
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
        operation.getResponse().responseText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response json should be in following format in Ajax request

```
{results:[{"id":"1", "name":"note 1"},{"id":"2", "name":"note 2"},{"id":"3", "name":"note 3"}]}
```

id and name are properties of your model NOte.

For jsonp,

in your  server side, get value from 'callback'. that value contains a name of callback method. Then concat that method name to your result string and write the response.

Then the json string should be in following format

```
callbackmethod({results:[{"id":"1", "name":"note 1"},{"id":"2", "name":"note 2"},{"id":"3", "name":"note 3"}]});
```